# Quick way to find USB id based on USB path

Tags: shell-script, usb, serial-port

I have a number of USB to serial cables and I'm looking for an easy way to find their `/dev/serial/by-id` value based on the `/dev/ttyUSB` path.

For instance, the id of the USB attached to `ttyUSB3` is `usb-FTDI_TTL232R-3V3_**FT93XIK5**-if00-port0` where **FT93XIK5** is the serial number of the device.

I want to obtain either the id or the serial based on the `ttyUSB` number. I know `dmesg` gives me that information:

```
[534200.345749] usb 2-1.1.1: SerialNumber: **FT93XIK5**
[534200.348402] ftdi_sio 2-1.1.1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[534200.348425] usb 2-1.1.1: Detected FT232RL
[534200.349040] usb 2-1.1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to **ttyUSB20**
```

and I can just write a script to extract the serial but I'm wondering if there's a quicker way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files inside `/dev/serial/by-id` directory are links pointing to `/dev/ttyUSB*`, so the standard tool one can use is `find`:

```
find -L /dev/serial/by-id/ -samefile /dev/ttyUSB3
```

- `-L` means to follow symbolic links
- `-samefile` means to get exactly the same inode as `/dev/ttyUSB3`